# Communication between browser addon and C# application

Tags: c#, javascript, browser-addons

Can anyone help me about my project?I'm trying to create an application using c# that will capture the Active URL of a browser and then scan it to a database for comparison.
My 1st approach is to create a javascript addon that will get/capture the url, but the problem is that I don't know how to send the captured data such as the url to my C# app..

Thanks guys..

Comment: Which browser are you targeting?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox and Google chrome

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not intimently familiar with Browser addin development, based on [this Google Chrome documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) why wouldn't you be able to host a HttpWebListener from your C# app and connect to it using [XHR](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)?